Asymptotic Distribution of the Product of Beta and Binomial
Suppose that $X_{n} \sim \frac{Binomial(n, p)}{n}$ and $Y_{n} \sim F^{-1}(Beta(n/2 + 1/2, n/2 + 1/2))$, where $\{X\}$ and $\{Y\}$ are independent and $F: [0, 1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{+}$. Define $Z_{n} = X_{n}Y_{n}$. Does $\sqrt{n}(Z_{n} - \mu_{n})$ have a well defined asymptotic distribution, where $\mu_{n} = \mathbb{E}[Z_{n}]$? I know that $\sqrt{n}(X_{n} - \mathbb{E}[X_{n}])$ and $\sqrt{n}(Y_{n} - \mathbb{E}[Y_{n}])$ converge to normality, but I am not sure if their product does. In my particular setup $X_{n}$ comes from a binomial proportion and $Y_{n}$ is the median of a set of values. I first tried to somehow write out the product as a sum, but that didn't work. I then considered trying to use characteristic functions, but the characteristic function for the beta distribution looks difficult to work with.
Thanks!


You say that $X_n$ converges to normality. Wouldn't it converge to the constant $p$ by th law of large numbers? To get convergence to normality, you'd want to divide by $\sqrt{n}$, not $n$.


With that in mind, probably Slutsky's theorem is the way to go.

Apologies, I am interested in convergence in distribution, so you are correct that I need to add a $\sqrt{n}$. I've edited the post.

In order to get normality from the $X_n$ terms and the $Y_n$ terms, we need to factors of $\sqrt{n}$. But we only have one. Which still makes me think that one of the two terms will converge in distribution to the normal and the other will converge to a constant. Slutsky's theorem is still the correct approach for the product.
